# Parsing piece of HTML using bash?

Tags: regex, bash, web-scraping

I want to parse out the tag name (first item) from docker hub using strictly bash.

Example:
https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags (input)

Output:

`latest`

This image latest tag is `latest` whereas mine as the most recent commits (dynamic). What is the best way to do this? I was able to use `wget` to store the contents into a string. I see xmllint, but not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: Please, proviode sample input and expected output

Comment: input would be that URL and the output would be `latest`

Comment: Not clear, you want to display the tag name of the node with 'latest' as text ?

Comment: I want to be able to grab the latest tag from the page, whatever the name may be. In the example URL I posted, the latest tag name is 'latest'

Comment: `<span class="styles__tagName___bE6Eb">latest</span>` ? Don't really see a tagname other than the class value.

Comment: Don't web scrape. Use a programmatic interface such as the [Registry HTTP API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags) or the `docker registry ls` CLI.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use basic tools such as wget or curl.

If you disable javascript in your browser, you can see that the page have no rendering content at all.

So the only one solution is to use a tool like [[image]puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) or [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) that are javascript capable